# C++: no matching function for call

Tags: c++, inheritance

This is the header file File.h:

```
#include "common.h"

#ifndef FILE_H
#define FILE_H
using namespace std;
class File : public fstream{
public:
        string file;
        File(){
                File("/tmp/text");
        }
        File(string file_name): file(file_name), fstream(file_name.c_str(), fstream::in | fstream::out){
        }
        void read_line();
};
#endif
```

And this is the File.cpp file:

```
#include "File.h"

void File::read_line(){
        string line;

        while(getline(*this, line)){
                cout << "line: " << line << endl;
        }
}
```

And following is the content of common.h

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <vector>
#include <string.h>
#include <string>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stack>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <cassert>
#include <stdexcept>
#include <getopt.h>
#include <fstream>
#include <istream>
```

When compiling above code, I get below error:

```
/home/rohit/cpp/cmake_projs/tree/src/File.cpp: In member function ‘void File::read_line()’:
/home/rohit/cpp/cmake_projs/tree/src/File.cpp:7:24: error: no matching function for call to ‘File::getline(File&, std::__cxx11::string&)’
  while(getline(*f, line)){
                        ^
In file included from /usr/include/c++/7/iostream:40:0,
                 from /home/rohit/cpp/cmake_projs/tree/include/common.h:1,
                 from /home/rohit/cpp/cmake_projs/tree/include/File.h:1,
                 from /home/rohit/cpp/cmake_projs/tree/src/File.cpp:1:
```

But the code compiles fine when I put almost same code in a different function not related to File class:

```
void test(){
        string line;
        File *f = new File("/tmp/abc");

        while(getline(*f, line)){
                cout << "line: " << line << endl;
        }
}
```

Why is this standard function hidden in the class function `read_line()` and not in an independent function?

Comment: Ditch `using namespace std;` and qualify all `std` members. Not much typing really, and will save you a lot of grief.

Comment: Thanks but why qualifying all `std` members solve the problem?

Comment: Because unqualified name lookup in C++ is an intricate process. And adding namespace pollution into the mix makes it go bust.

Comment: Thanks. But I wonder why my question was down-voted. Was my question incomplete, very easy to answer or less researched? I am a beginner and tried my level best to find the solution from the book by Bruce Eckel (that I have), here and there over the Internet. :) . And using the test() function approach was also a part of experiment. And I don't understand why namespace pollution busted test() approach.

Comment: I wouldn't know. I didn't downvote it.

Comment: Not a problem @StoryTeller :) Its just a question to general audience because I have experienced this like 2-3 times :)

Comment: @Rohit Maybe because there is too much irrelevant code that distracts from the thing you want to find out. Posting a [mcve] always helps.

Comment: Btw, if you are ever looking to refresh your book list, we have a curated list [available here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list).

Answer (score 1):

It is because fstream has a member getline that does not match, change the call to std::getline and it will work.

Answer (score 1):

It is a case of name lookup not working the way you expected.

Your class `File` inherits from `fstream` which inherits from `istream`. And `istream` has [`a member function getline`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/getline), or two actually.

When you call an unqualified `getline` inside the class member, the compiler finds the inherited `getline` member and then doesn't look any further. In the free function `test()` there is no member function, so the compiler instead looks for the functions brought in by `using namespace std;`.

A solution is to explicitly use `std::getline(*this, line)` to show that you want to call a free function and not a member function.

---

This might also be yet another reason for not doing `using namespace std;`, but instead use `std::` to refer to standard library names.